# Quantity value 0.0003 when rounded shows as 0.000 which is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some quantity value as 0.0003. If I round of, I get as 0.000 or 0.00 but it is wrong as per business and they want it to have as value 0.001 in SQL Server. Could someone please help me out?

I tried some but it is not working as expected.

[image: image1]

```
SELECT ROUND(0.0003, 0);  
GO  
SELECT ROUND(0.0003, 0, 1);   
GO

SELECT (CAST(0.0003 AS numeric(11,3)))

SELECT CAST(0.0003 AS decimal(9,2))
```

Comment: So what are your business rules? Round everything up?

Comment: @Dale K: well as of now we have some values as 0.0003 which I found while testing and they want to have the value as 0.001.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You need to be clear what your overall business logic is, rounding up is unusual.

Comment: And also clarify what should happen to `-0.0003`

Comment: Well!  we had only that one specific value. So followed your syntax and it worked fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your business rules are to round everything up to the nearest 1000th then the following might be what you want:

```
SELECT CEILING(0.0003*1000)/1000;
```

Returns `0.001`

Since `CEILING` only works on whole numbers you need to multiple by 1000 first then divide by 1000 afterwards.